# Why does running the following code with os.fork() in a Jupyter Notebook cause the notebook to crash?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run the following Python code in a Jupyter Notebook cell that utilizes os.fork() to create a child process. However, the notebook crashes when executing the cell. The code is as follows:

```
import os

def main():
    print("Starting process...")

    # Call os.fork() to create a child process
    pid = os.fork()

    if pid == 0:
        # This block runs in the child process
        print("I'm the child process!")
    else:
        # This block runs in the parent process
        print("I'm the parent process!")

    print("Exiting process...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Think about it: After a fork with no exec, you have two copies of the Jupyter Notebook kernel running at the same time, inheriting the file descriptors used to communicate with their parent processes. One has to design for that (f/e, by making sure those FDs are set not to be duplicated on fork and to ensure that the child process can handle the case when they're gone gracefully) to be able to tolerate it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the same problem with the jupyter notebook, which works with fine when running as a script from the command line.

In the jupyter notebook's run log, I see:

```
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yinghaodang/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 409, in dispatch_shell
    await result
  File "/home/yinghaodang/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 755, in execute_request
    if not silent and reply_msg["content"]["status"] == "error" and stop_on_error:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I didn't get into how the source code was implemented, nor was I able to do so.

I simply accept that the jupyter notebook doesn't support the fork function. All I know is that the fork function creates a child process that shares memory with the parent process.

if you want the above code to work property, you can do this:

```
import os

def main():
    print("Starting process...")

    # Call os.fork() to create a child process
    pid = os.fork()

    if pid == 0:
        # This block runs in the child process
        print("I'm the child process!")
        os._exit(os.EX_OK)
    else:
        # This block runs in the parent process
        print("I'm the parent process!")

    print("Exiting process...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Or do this:

Don't use `fork` in the notebook, but write it in a script, in notebook, use
modual subprocess to spawn a new process. In your script, you can use `fork function`.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["python", "my_script.py"])
```

The following information is from the Internet, may not be correct:

> Use a kernel that supports forked processes, like an IPython kernel. Some options:
>
> - IPython: `ipython kernel install --name "ipython-with-fork" --user`
> - Jupyter console: `jupyter console --kernel ipython-with-fork`